# To calculate the mean and variance of a column of subset of a data using awk

Tags: command-line, awk

I want to calculate the mean and variance of a column after filtering the dataset by another column. For example, with dataset:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
```

I want the result:

```
0 3 2.5
1 3 2.5
2 3 2.5
```

with the classificatory variable in the first colum and the mean e variance in the second and third columns, respectively.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? Have you considered using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)?

Comment: I want an awk script that gives me the result in a single file. I can do it separately, first filter the data set then apply the formulas to the mean and variance that are in separate files. I was thinking of implementing this in a loop, but I do not know how.

Comment: I can´t  install datamash because I'm not root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Welford’s method for computing variance](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/) and assuming that the variances are non-zero (i.e. that there is more than one instance of each category):

```
awk '
  {count[$1]++; sum[$1]+=$2; sumsq[$1]+=$2*$2} 
  END {
    for(i in count) {m = sum[i]/count[i]; print i, m, (sumsq[i] - count[i]*m**2)/(count[i]-1)}
  }
' dataset
0 3 2.5
1 3 2.5
2 3 2.5
```

Trapping the zero-variance case is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -W -g 1 mean 2 svar 2 < file
```

Explanation:

- `-W` Use whitespace as delimiter
- `-g 1` Group by field 1
- `mean 2` Print mean of field 2
- `svar 2` Print sample variance of field 2

See more operations [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Available-Operations.html).

---

Install `datamash` with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install datamash
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can´t  install datamash because I'm not root. Is there any other way to do it using awk?